# Using an array of strings for UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to change a UILabel with strings based on an array.  Here is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
   scanLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.f", [sender value]];
    NSString *wholeText = @"Very Bad";
    self.scanLabel.text = wholeText;

}
```

Instead of just "Very Bad," I want different values to show "very Bad, Bad, Okay, Good, Very Good."

Where do I declare the NSMutableArray, and how do I implement it with the slider?

Update: Thank you all for your help! (I love stackoverflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not compiler checked...but you may get some idea.

```
NSArray *texts=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"very Bad", @"Bad", @"Okay", @"Good", @"Very Good",nil];
NSInteger sliderValue=[sender value]; //make the slider value in given range integer one.
self.scanLabel.text=[texts objectAtIndex:sliderValue];
```

Comment: welcome Adam. I would be happy if this i am able to help you. But I am  unsure this code is valid, plz check it in compiler and let me know for any modifications.

Comment: It is valid. The only thing you were missing was the ", nil" at the end of the array! :)  Thanks again Anoop!

Comment: @Adam: Thanks... this means i am still learning obj-c. A long way to go... :)

Comment: Hey Anoop, this may be a bit offtopic, but do you know if I'm able to change the font color for each string?  Tricky one, I know..

Answer (score 3):

You declare it in the same class as the above method.

Let's say it's called `wholeTexts`.

The code will look like this:

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    scanLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.f", [sender value]];
    NSString *wholeText = [wholeTexts objectAtIndex:(wholeTexts.count - 1) * (int)(sender.value - sender.minimumValue)/(sender.maximumValue - sender.minimumValue)];
    self.scanLabel.text = wholeText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the array anywhere you want, as long as it's created before you need to use the slider. Sliders can only have a value between 0 and 1 in iOS, so you'll need to multiply the value by something to get numbers as high as the number of items in your array (minus 1), and you'll need to convert them to an integer, so you can use that value as the index into the array. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
   scanLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:(int)(sender.value * 10)];

}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `scanLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:(int)[sender value] * 10]`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No, if you do it your way, the value will always be 0 or 1, since casting a number between 0 and 1 to an int will always give you 0 or 1 (I think -- actually I don't know the order of execution here. Does the cast happen first or the multiplication).

Comment: Sliders can have a `double` max and min value... there is no issue setting min 0.0 and max 4.0.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, I did have my punctuation wrong though, and I fixed that. I checked your way, it does give 0 for anything less than 1.

Comment: @rdelmar: i dint check your answer, but i thuoght must be somehing missing as you need to multiply `sender value` by 10. And i am learning ios, so little bit of new thing for me... anywaz its good that we reached at correct solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put your text values into an array

```
NSArray* array =  @[@"very Bad", @"Bad", @"Okay", @"Good", @"Very Good"];
```

- set your slider to have a min value of 0 and maximum value of 4
- turn your `[sender value]` into an `int`, eg `floor([sender value])`

pick an item from the array using your int, eg

```
NSString* result = [array objectAtIndex:myInt];
```